# SVN and Jenkins for C# on same machine (ubuntu)

Tags: c#, svn, ubuntu, jenkins

i am facing the following problem. I would like to implement the approach of CI with jenkins into my Project. The project is written in C#. 
I have an ubuntu server v. 12.0.4.2 LTS. The idea is to run subversion and Jenkins on this Machine, while i am not sure, whether i understand the technical part correct. In my researches i was reading about a CI-Server, so obviously here is the jenkins, and a Build Server. 
So my question is: Can i run subversion and Jenkins on the same machine?
If this is the case, i would really appreciate some advice.

Until now i have installed Jenkins, which is working. I have also installed subversion, but because i am kinda new to linux, i dont know whether my SVN is working correctly.
My understanding of Subversion with Jenkins is, that i create a Repository in a specific directory on my server. 
Jenkins is monitoring this Directory and starts the build+tests after a commit happened. 
But how do i acces the Repository Path from my working machine?

**EDIT**
My Location tag of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default looks like this

```
<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /home/svn
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "mml"
 AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The path to my Repositorys is /home/svn/ in this Path i want to have my project called mml.
The access.log is empty, but the error.log is has this error: [Tue May 07 17:41:48 2013] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) from 77.21.150.76 ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's completely possible to host Jenkins and Subversion on the same server.

Subversion has a few access methods.  You can decide which one you want (SSH, http or https over WebDav via a web server like Apache, file over a Samba share, or something else) and implement that.  Fortunately it seems as if Ubuntu's Server Guide has a section on just this sort of thing, discussing all the methods and how to set them up: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/subversion.html

Good luck, and welcome to the wonderful world of autobuild!  =)

Comment: Ok, so im on the right way. Thanks for the Information so far. The Problem i am facing ATM is, that i have configured SVN and added a Repo. If i use `svn co http://hostname/svn/myproject myproject --username test` i receive `svn: OPTIONS of http://hostname/svn/myproject : OK (http://hostname)`. But if i try to call the Repo from my working machine by going to http://my-Ubuntu-IP/svn via Browser i get a Status Code: 404. I have followed the installtion guide of subversion really detailed and still dont know what the problem might be.

Comment: Did you follow the "Access via WebDAV protocol (http://)" section in that link?  You should be able to visit the URL in a web browser and get back a list of files or directories, if it's set up correctly.  If it isn't, double-check your apache or other webserver configuration and check your access / error logs.

Comment: Yes i did, and i also double checked everything. In case i made something wrong: is there something like a System Recovery to undo all changes made? Or undo all chnages + uninstall everything except SSH?Maybe i need to start from scratch again in case i did something wrong at jenkins/apache setup

Comment: I doubt you need to start over.  What does your Location tag look like in apache.conf?  Did you do `svnadmin create` somewhere in the corresponding directory?  If so, do you see anything interesting in `access_log` or `error_log` when you try to access after restarting apache that suggests what might be going on?

Comment: i solved the mentioned sub-issue in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441937/subversion-status-code-404/)

Comment: Ah, great -- sorry for not getting back sooner, it was a crazy week.  Good to hear it's working!  =)