# subversion status code 404

Tags: svn, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

i do want to run subversion on my ubuntu 12.04. In fact i have already installed it (v.1.6). 
I have also configured the /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf so it looks like this:

```
<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /repo/mml
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Subversion Repository"
 AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I have added a User+Password to the mentioned file and did chown -R www-data:www-data /repo .
Now if i try to browse to my repo on my working machine using

```
http://myserver/svn
```

im getting "Status Code: 404" without any Exception or Stacktrace!
If i try to go to

```
http://localhost/svn
```

on the server im getting

```
"-bash: http://localhost/svn: No such file or directory".
```

I have checked the apache error.log but there are no errors. My acces.log is empty.

Do you have any idea of what i might did wrong in my configuration?
Do you have any idea of what could go wrong?

**EDIT**:
I think i figured out what the Problem is. I created a config file for jenkins which routes incomming request on port 80 to port 8080 `/etc/apache2/sites-available/jenkins`. If i delete this configuration, i can not access jenkins from my working machine anymore, because `http://my-ip:8080` times out. This is my VirtualHost config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName ci.company.com
 ServerAlias ci
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost on
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I found out a solution to this Problem. The key is to use jenkins with a prefix. Define `--prefix=/jenkins` in the jenkins ARGS in `/etc/default/jenkins`. After this you are able to proxy pass /jenkins requests, see the updated config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName ci.company.com
 ServerAlias ci
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost on
 ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution to this Problem. The key is to use jenkins with a prefix. Define `--prefix=/jenkins` in the jenkins ARGS in `/etc/default/jenkins`. After this you are able to proxy pass /jenkins requests, see the updated config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName ci.company.com
 ServerAlias ci
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost on
 ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

404 HTTP status is "Not Found".   In Subversion, it may be related..  some pages suggest permission problems can also be a possible cause.

Did you do a `chmod -R 770 /repo/mml/*`?

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-09/0601.shtml

Comment: yes i tried this already, without any success. Maybe it is interesting to note, that i get an authentification pop up while accesing the repo. after the auth the 404 thingy appears. do i need to have a project in my repo to be able to browse it, or can i just create a repo, connect to it via working machiene and commit an initial project?maybe that is the reason? I have also read something about WebSVn while i am still not sure,whether i need it or not.

Comment: Should `<SNVPath>` have the /mml on the end? Maybe just /repo would be better.

Comment: SVNPath is the direct Path to my Repository. SVNParentPath would be correct for /repo. At least if understand the comments in the file correct: " #SVNPath /var/lib/svn
  # Alternatively, use SVNParentPath if you have multiple repositories under
  # under a single directory (/var/lib/svn/repo1, /var/lib/svn/repo2, ...).
  # You need either SVNPath and SVNParentPath, but not both.
  #SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
"